# rails, syntax error, unexpected ','

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have several conditions in my search.

```
@events = Event.search(params[:search], 
  :conditions => {:group_size => 1, :days => 1})
```

The above code is working fine. However, if I want to replace the hash with a private method, I get syntax error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
    :conditions => {group_size_condition, :days => 1},
```

Code is as follow

```
@events = Event.search(params[:search], 
  :conditions => {group_size_condition, :days => 1})

private

def group_size_condition
  if params[:groupsize] == 'single (1)'
    :group_size => 1
  elsif params[:groupsize] == 'couple (2)'
    :group_size => 2
  elsif params[:groupsize] == 'small group(3-5)'
    :group_size => 3..5
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be work

```
@events = Event.search(params[:search], 
  :conditions => group_size_condition.merge(:days => 1))

private

def group_size_condition
  case params[:groupsize]
  when 'single (1)' then {:group_size => 1}
  when 'couple (2)' then {:group_size => 2}
  when 'small group(3-5)' then {:group_size => 3..5}
  else
    {}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed :group_size key

```
@events = Event.search(params[:search], 
  :conditions => {:group_size => group_size_condition, :days => 1})
```

Comment: I think I also need to change the private method. It should only return the value, instead of the entire condition.

Comment: an irrelevant question, @pkubicki. basically I want to ignore the groupsize search condition if groupsize fall into 'else' condition. It looks like nil is not correct in this case. Do you know how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you want to actually pass the string, as in:

```
def group_size_condition
  if params[:groupsize] == 'single (1)'
    ':group_size => 1'
  elsif params[:groupsize] == 'couple (2)'
    ':group_size => 2'
  elsif params[:groupsize] == 'small group(3-5)'
    ':group_size => 3..5'
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the quick turnaround. But the above code does not work. Still get the same error.